# How to interactively use tDOM?

Tags: tcl, tdom

I feel that I'm missing something subtle here.

I have a `$doc` which I can see with `$doc asText` really contains the content of the page to be parsed. It came from `dom parse -html5 $body`.

From here, I'd like to interactively explore the DOM. For example, to get a list of anchors. It seems like `$doc selectNodes {//a}` would work*, but that doesn't return anything. Neither does anything else I try with `selectNodes` (/head, /body, /html ...nothing!). I can see that there are `childNodes` so the structure seems to be intact.

What is the better way to explore these nodes so I can figure out what is going wrong?

- https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/XPath - this is what I was trying to follow

Comment: Are you using `selectNodes` on the root element like the example on the linked wiki page does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your life, this time, as you seem to work with HTML (not XML, or XHTML for that matter) because you pass `-html5` to `dom parse`, and you select for HTML elements (anchors).

So far, HTML has no meaning of namespaces, so you may ignore them. Use the [-ignorexmlns](http://tdom.org/index.html/doc/trunk/doc/dom.html) flag to `dom parse`.

```
% package req tdom
0.9.2
% set someHTML {<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title></head><body>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>}
% set doc [dom parse -html5 -ignorexmlns $someHTML]
```

This way, you will be able to run your XPath queries, expressions w/o namespace awareness:

```
$doc selectNodes {//svg}
```

Note that is a recommended use of [tDOM](http://tdom.org/index.html/doc/trunk/doc/dom.html):

> Since this probably isn't wanted by a lot of users and adds only burden for no good in a lot of use cases -html5 can be combined with -ignorexmlns, in which case all nodes and attributes in the DOM tree are not in an XML namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Running `$doc asXML` reveals that the html element has been parsed into a namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

You will have to use this namespace to find elements:

```
$doc selectNodes -namespaces {ns http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml} //ns:a
```

If you are going to do multiple queries, it will be easier to set up the namespace once:

```
$doc selectNodesNamespaces {ns http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}
$doc selectNodes //ns:a
$doc selectNodes /ns:html
```

et cetera.

Comment: XPath has always been something of a pain with XML namespaces, and not just in this library and language; it is actually better than most!

Comment: The xmlns default namespace is merely an artifact, it is produced as the default namespace by spec-compliant parsers that read HTML into XML (XHTML) or when serializing an HTML DOM into XHTML. Namespaces should simply be ignored in this setting. See my answer.

Comment: @mrcalvin That's even easier. +1 for your answer.